# Why my touchpad not working?

Tags: touchpad

My laptop is an ASUS K53SC. It has an ELANTECH touchpad. It becomes unresponsive after password screen at each reboot.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the touchpad drivers may help.

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-core xorg-input-abi-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to my touchpad after installing Kubuntu 14.04. I went to System Settings -> Input Devices -> Touchpad -> enable/disable touchpad -> Keyboard shortcuts.

There was no keyboard shortcut onfigured for enabling and disabling touchpad, so I set up one then I just used it and the touchpad somehow started working again.
Hope this helps.